# Complex Binding in SAPUI5 XML View

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to convert a string value to Boolean while binding it from a JSONModel. Ideally the value in my model is "true"/"false" and I want to bind it to the visible property of an item. The model is defined to be TwoWay binding but I guess that does not matter in this case

I have declared "complex binding" in the index.html.

```
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
```

Then I create my XML view and bind the property from the model as below:

```js
<P13nColumnsItem>
  columnKey="{tableVariantAFModel>Fieldname}" 
visible="{path:'tableVariantAFModel>Visible', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Boolean', mode: 'sap.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay'}" 
index="{tableVariantAFModel>DisplayOrder}">
  <P13nColumnsItem>
```

When I run my app,it throws the below error:
[image]

Is there any step I am missing?
Also, I need to add this app to the Fiori Launchpad, so I need to define the complex binding in **manifest.json** file rather than in index.html . Where can I define it in the manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would advise to use a formatter. See [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/25/ab54b0113c4914999c43d07d3b71fe/content.htm). In the formatter you could write:

```
visible="{path:'tableVariantAFModel>Visible', formatter: '.formatter.stringToBoolean'}"
```

in the formatter you could create the function like:

```
stringToBoolean: function(_stringBoolean){
    (_stringBoolean === "true") ? return true : return false;
}
```

You have to make sure that you instantiate the formatter in your controller, or optionally you could choose a function in your controller itself.

Comment: Thanks Matti. I am currently using formatters itself. SAPUI5 documentation says formatters are trivial. Also, how do I define my complex binding in manifest file??

Comment: That depends on your UI5 version, but generally speaking you should be able to add settings to your model. Add value defaultBindingMode with TwoWay.

Answer (score 3):

For simple use cases like this you can use an expression binding instead of implementing additional logic somewhere.

```
<P13nColumnsItem>
  columnKey="{tableVariantAFModel>Fieldname}" 
  visible="{= ${tableVariantAFModel>Visible} === 'true'}" 
  index="{tableVariantAFModel>DisplayOrder}">
<P13nColumnsItem>
```

Comment: sweet! Thanks @matbtt

Comment: Here is the [sap help link](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/da/f6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0/content.htm).